# Why PuTTY doesn't accept SSH key exchange RSA algorithm

Tags: ssh, putty, rsa

**Summary:**
I am trying to set SSH key exchange algorithm to RSA with no luck.
The session is between my Windows machine with PuTTY as client to a Linux machine in Amazon EC2.

**Description:**
I configured PuTTY to use the RSA-based key exchange algorithm for the key exchange and removed GSSAPI:
[image]

I also set the `Hostkeys` field to use RSA:
[image]

But when I starts the session, it seems that it still uses the ECDH algorithm:
[image]

What can be the reason that it doesn't accept the RSA algorithm?

Comment: Maybe SSH server is configured not to accept RSA key exchange. You can check that in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. If that is not the case, then you can also configure debug logging for SSH server and check its log how it selects the algorithm.

Comment: Are you running an old version of putty? Make sure you have the latest release.